# Store paragraphs of text (including line breaks) in cloud kit and query

Tags: ios, swift, cloudkit

I have another newbie question. Hopefully one of you programming gurus can help me with it.

I'm trying to fetch multiple paragraphs of text (e.g. a news article) from CloudKit. I don't know how to format the text so that it includes a line break. I've been told that I should use CKAsset instead of a String on the CloudKit record, but I don't understand how it's supposed to be formatted.

Can anyone help me understand this more?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Would it suffice to have `\n` as the new line identifier? CKAsset is the way to go, you just need to:

- create the file
- create asset with the file's url
- save it to database
- remove the temp file afterwards.

When you get the record from CloudKit:

- access it's file path
- load the data using `NSFileManager`
- decode the data (this uses `NSString`, which is a bore, but don't know any other way)

Save Record:

```
let str = "sample \n string save to file"
if let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSTemporaryDirectory())?.URLByAppendingPathComponent("tempFile", isDirectory: false) {
    if str.writeToURL(url, atomically: true, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: nil) {
        let asset = CKAsset(fileURL: url)
        let record = CKRecord(recordType: "TextAsset")
        record.setValue(asset, forKey: "text")
        CKContainer.defaultContainer().publicCloudDatabase.saveRecord(record) { savedRecord, error in
            if error != nil {
                println(error)
            } else {
                println(savedRecord)
            }
            // do this in completion closure, otherwise the file gets deleted before uploading
            NSFileManager.defaultManager().removeItemAtURL(url, error: nil)
        }
    }
}
```

Load record:

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(value: true)
let query = CKQuery(recordType: "TextAsset", predicate: predicate)
CKContainer.defaultContainer().publicCloudDatabase.performQuery(query, inZoneWithID: nil) { queryRecords, error in
    if let records = queryRecords {
        for record in records {
            let asset = record.valueForKey("text") as! CKAsset
            if let content = NSFileManager.defaultManager().contentsAtPath(asset.fileURL.path!) {
                let text = NSString(data: content, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
                println(text)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Remember to handle errors appropriately, this is just a showcase sample code.

Comment: Hi, this is going to be a really dumb question, but what program do I store the bulk text in?

Comment: The idea is that I upload text directly to the cloud kit database. I won't actually save any data in the app and upload it.

Comment: You save the text to file by calling `str.writeToURL` just to get URL to create `CKAsset`. After its saved to cloud, you delete it in completion closure with `NSFileManager.defaultManager().removeItemAtURL(url, error: nil)`